# Detecting the number of ORACLE rows updated by a OCI OCIStmtExecute call

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have an ORACLE update statement that I call using the OCIStmtExecute function call.

Using an OCI function call I would like to know how many rows have been updated by the action, e.g. zero, one or more.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the OCIAttrGet function call on your OCIStmt statement handle with the attribute type set to OCI_ATTR_ROW_COUNT

So add the folllowing code to your program :

```
   ub4 row_count;

   rc = OCIAttrGet ( stmthp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, &row_count, 0, OCI_ATTR_ROW_COUNT,
           errhp );
```

where:

`stmthp` is the OCIStmt statement handle

`errhp` is the OCIError error handle

`rc` is the defined return code (sword)

The number of rows updated (or deleted and inserted if that is your operation) is written into the passed row_count variable

Answer (score 2):

Invoke `OCIAttrGet(OCI_ATTR_ROW_COUNT)` on the statement handle.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi I'd just worked it out too myself and have posted an answer as well. Thanks for looking at it.